# How can I execute different Javascript functions on page load, depending on the action called?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to figure out a way to call specific java script function conditionally, Suppose I have 4 links in a page and I am not using `<f:ajax>`, when user clicks on 1-link then testJs1() need to call and so on, I searched for omnifaces onloadScript, seems its a good option to execute common js functions, not individually.

Looking for way to do this because, Suppose in a page I have four sections like mail,news,update and edit . all these will be commandLink, So I wanna to invoke individual js after click event complete.

for example:

```
<h:commandLink id="discussions" action="#{connectDashBoardBean.navigateToDiscussion}" title="Click To Partcipate" 
            styleClass="#{connectDashBoardBean.discussionUpdateFlg ? 'favMenuSelected':'favMenu'}">
            <div id="discussion" class="favContentHead">
                <div class="favContentHeadImg">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/test/discussion.jpeg" height="20" width="20" />
                </div>
                <div class="favContentHeadText">
                    <h:outputText value="Start Discussing" />
                </div>
                <div class="favContentHeadUpdate">
                    <h:outputText value="1M+" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <f:param name="sessionKey" value="1234" />
            <f:param name="ref" value="1234" />
            <f:param name="pId" value="1234" />
            <!-- <f:ajax onevent="testing"/> -->
        </h:commandLink>
```

and similarly 3 more `<h:commandLink>` are there and action method returning `null`, so It will stay in same page but different component will be loaded to DOM tree, so If I will make a common JS function then one JS might get failed to applied to DOM tree, as that component is not yet there, SO I want to call specific js function when that component is getting added to DOM tree, that I thought of calling individual JS call on click of each link, is there any way to do?

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more and post some snippet? it's not easy to understand what you try to accomplish

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez Hello Updated the question, Please let me know I need to give more info.

Comment: So you want to execute a specific JS function when the user clicks on such a `h:commandLink`? Or is there anything the [onclick](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html) attribute can't do for you?

Comment: @mabi onclick is not helping me, as DOM tree is not yet updated, I want to make call to that jsFunction when DOM tree is complete, Similar to, If I am using <f:ajax>, then on success event, DOM tree is updated and it make sense calling the jsFunction, But my case I can't make use of <f:ajax> here.

Comment: Looking at your condition a4j:commandButton might be helpful to you

Comment: @psi the OP specified he can't use <f:ajax/>, which is what a4j:commandButton does under the hood (though I agree that'd be my solution as well)

Comment: @psi: Thank you, but after looking at documentation The <a4j:commandButton> component is used in the same way as JSF <h:commandButton> . The difference is that in case of <a4j:commandButton> the components to be updated should be specified.which is same way as <f:ajax>, here I want to avoid that, I mean I don't want to give any render things, any other way I can track commandLink execution completed?